# How to create 2 to N associations in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Previously my table would associate records on a one to one basis so I simply stored the ID of the associated record model on its partner record.

I updated my model to allow these records to be associated with many other records as long as they had the same values in several columns. I added a new table to my database that would store a unique grouping ID for each set of associated records. I also added a column to my model so that associated records could hold a reference to their grouping ID.

I have two tables in play here. The main table which we can call "record" and then a "recordAssociation" table.

The model really doesn't matter other than:

Record
PK guid | {then some fields, in our case address1, address2, city, zip etc.} | FK RecordAssociationId guid

RecordAssociation
PK guid

How would I populate the association table and update the record table.

Comment: 2 to N? It should be interesting scenario. what is the use case? can you provide a simplified version of your model?

Comment: slicedbread's coworker here: We essentially have a self referencing table  that went from 0:1 to 0:many. We created an association table that just had audit information and a primary key. We then relate things records to the primary table. It wasn't specifically necessary to create this extra table but it made things much cleaner in our app layer. 
But the 2:many comes in where we don't want to create an association record or set the FK on the main table when it is not actually related to anything. I.E. we didn't want groups of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that we came up with:

```
--Start by setting up a temp table so we can do joins
declare @recordAssociationTemp table
(
UniqueId VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
NewAssociationId uniqueidentifier NULL,
CreatedBy uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
);

--Select the columns we want to associate on by making a unique ID out of the common fields
with temp as
(
select isnull(AddressLineOne, '') + isnull(AddressLineTwo, '') + isnull(AddressCity, '') + isnull(AddressState, '') + isnull(AddressZip,'')+ isnull(a.CreatedBy,'') as UniqueId,
a.CreatedBy,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by isnull(AddressLineOne, '') + isnull(AddressLineTwo, '') + isnull(AddressCity, '') + isnull(AddressState, '') + isnull(AddressZip,'')
+ isnull(a.CreatedBy,'') order by a.CreatedBy) as RowNum
from dbo.[Record] as a inner join DGSystem as dgs on a.SystemId = dgs.Id
)
--ROW_NUMBER() helps us assign an increasing ID to each duplicate row so we can avoid making associations for records that only have a single entry 
insert @recordAssociationTemp (UniqueId, CreatedBy)
select distinct UniqueId, CreatedBy
from temp
where RowNum > 1; -- > 1 allows us to skip over records that don't have any associations 

update @recordAssociationTemp
set NewAssociationId = NEWID();

--this is where we add new records to our association table with the generated unique IDs and some accociated audit data
insert into dbo.RecordAssociation
(Id, CreatedBy, CreatedDateTime, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDateTime)
select NewAssociationId, CreatedBy, SYSDATETIME(), CreatedBy, SYSDATETIME()
from @recordAssociationTemp;

--finally, we join our temp table to apply our new IDs to the record table
update a
set a.RecordAssociationId = aat.NewAssociationId
from dbo.[Record] as a inner join DGSystem as dgs on a.SystemId = dgs.Id
inner join @recordAssociationTemp as aat on isnull(AddressLineOne, '') + isnull(AddressLineTwo, '') + isnull(AddressCity, '') + isnull(AddressState, '') + isnull(AddressZip,'')
+ isnull(a.CreatedBy,'') = aat.UniqueId;
```

Comment: Is this an answer or an extension of your question?

Comment: It is an answer to my own question. I made that more clear now. Thanks!